# error MSB8007: The Platform for project XXX is invalid. Platform='x64'

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I have switched from a 32 bits to a 64 bits laptop and I am trying to `npm install` a `node.js` project with a dependency to `"swisseph": "0.5.6"`.

Everything was working fine under 32 bits, but now it is not working anymore. I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\jverstrynge\Documents\Private\Free Time\ChartVibes>npm install
|
> swisseph@0.5.6 install C:\Users\jverstrynge\Documents\Private\Free Time\ChartVibes\node_modules\swisseph
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\jverstrynge\Documents\Private\Free Time\ChartVibes\node_modules\swisseph>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platf
orm for project 'swissephz.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying
to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this proje
ct. [C:\Users\jverstrynge\Documents\Private\Free Time\ChartVibes\node_modules\swisseph\build\deps\swisseph\swissephz.vc
xproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jverstrynge\Documents\Private\Free Time\ChartVibes\node_modules\swisseph
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! swisseph@0.5.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the swisseph@0.5.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the swisseph package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls swisseph
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jverstrynge\Documents\Private\Free Time\ChartVibes\npm-debug.log
```

I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express installed. Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a node-gyp issue, not explicitly an issue with being on a 64 bit os. Read the node-gyp setup instructions to make sure everything is configured correctly. You may be missing the 64 bit SDK. https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Try upgrading to VS2015 Express.

Answer (score 0):

To build x64 project with Visual C++ 2010 Express download and install the [Windows Software Development Kit version 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Visual C++ 2010 Express does not include a 64 bit compiler, but the SDK does. If you still doesn't have x64 compiler for Visual C++ 2010 please read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277